# Перестановки неограниченной длины на python

Tags: python, алгоритм

Я хочу получить итератор на все возможные строки, представляющие собой перестановки из символов имеющегося алфавита.
К примеру, при алфавите ('0', '1') и длине строки 3 я хочу получить:

```
"000", "001", "010", ... "110", "111"
```

К сожалению, модуль itertools мне это сделать не даёт: если длина строки превосходит длину алфавита, то permutation просто создаёт пустой итератор.
Лично мне не особо принципиально, я могу сделать что-то типа такого:

```
alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
for a in alphabet:
  for b in alphabet:
    # Смысл дальше, думаю, понятен
```

Ни в документации, ни на форумах я, к сожалению, не нашёл решения подобной проблемы. Но мне просто интересно: 1) верно ли, что itertools не предоставляет такой функционал? Но если да, то 2) можно ли обойтись без "наивного" кода сверху?

Comment: А почему бы не почитать документацию по [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) если просто интересно?

Comment: TigerTV.ru, хороший вопрос. Серьёзно, я там этого не нашёл

Comment: а это видели `# product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111` там? Ну, не видели так не видели. Теперь знаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во первых есть стандартная библиотека `itertools` и функция `product`:

```
import itertools

print(*itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=3))
```

во вторых данную задачу можно свести к перебору чисел от `0` до `N^M - 1`, где `M` - кол-во цифр, `N` - система счисления

например в вашем примере имеется 2-ричная система со словарем `(0, 1)`, а всего соответственно может быть `2^3` вариантов и значит надо перебрать все числа до 8 и каждое перевести из 10 ричной в 2ричную систему:

```
dictionary = ('0', '1')
size = 3
for i in range(len(dictionary)**size):
    value = i
    res = []
    for j in range(size):
        digit = value % len(dictionary)
        value = (value - digit) // len(dictionary)
        res.append(dictionary[digit])

    print(res[::-1])
```